# wkhtmltopdf with full image background on all pages

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

How can I make an image background to display on the last page in full height?
It cuts it when the HTML content ends. The content of the HTML varies, so cutting it in pages before wkhtmltopdf parses it is not a viable option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who might end up searching for an answer:
wkhtmltopdf does not support background to be added to each page, but PDFtk is a helpful tool. I generated the pdf with wkhtmltopdf and saved it as a tmp file, then reopened with PDFtk and added the desired background to each page.